# AN separate text object - separate to words?

Tags: animation-nodes

I’m trying to separate text into words and make transformation on separate words elements with falloff. As on screen I handle with transformation falloff (y +2.79) but question is how to distribute each word to line up into paragraph (transform word by length of word before in loop ?)

[image]

@Omar Ahmad
ready solution with Omar help
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to compute the distance recursively inside a loop like this:

[image]

I get the width of each word using the dimensions vector, by adding all the width of all the words before each word, I know the location of my word with some space in between.

Comment: I was exactly looking for this. Thank You.