# Animation Nodes - Have Text Appear Word By Word Instead Of Letter By Letter

Tags: animation-nodes, text-object

Using setup with a text object
[image]

Typewriter text displays letter by letter
[image]

Can this be altered to display word by word?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/an-separate-text-object-separate-to-words

Comment: I tried the above ^ https://i.postimg.cc/t4PXT3F5/screenshot-2020-07-12.png My setup must not have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Split text into words. then slice text list based on frame and combine back to single text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for me is to use directional falloff with initial setup, keyframes have to be constant.
[image]

[image]