# Is there a way to make word per word filling text effect like in AfterFX?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to buy a plugin or make a good text transition with the video editor, like the ones that after effects make?

Specifically a word per word filling text effect, like a text machine from the 70s.

I'm using blender 2.82.

Thank you in advance, I cannot pay the after-effects program.

Comment: I would encourage you to edit your question and specify what your goals are. AE is capable of a very large range of text (and other) animation. What is it *specifically* you are trying to achieve in blender?

Comment: Please avoid all caps. It is considered yelloing. No need to be rude. https://danieltitus.com/blog/advertising/237-why-all-caps-is-usually-a-bad-idea

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186153/animation-nodes-have-text-appear-word-by-word-instead-of-letter-by-letter and https://github.com/gandalf3/blender-typewriter-addon

Comment: Oh, Im sorry, my apologies :)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed. If you just want to make the text move across the screen you can always keyframe the text position in the style settings. [image]

Or you can try and make your own more complicated animations with the [Text Effects](https://blendermarket.com/products/ik-text-effects) plugin. In the 3D viewport you can create and render the text object to make complex and interesting transitions and animations.

Comment: interesting, thanks, a bit expensive though

Comment: You can always keyframe yourself, or look around for a free option